# How to get scroll position to a textView from an array in Android?

Tags: java, android, scroll, textview

I have created an array which contains a lots of textViews. I want to scroll down automatically to the `statistics[i]` `textView`. I tried to use `scrollView.scrollTo(0, statistics[i].getBottom());` but nothing happend. Any ideas?
This is my code:

```
TextView[] statistics;

final LinearLayout mainLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
this.setContentView(mainLinearLayout);

final RelativeLayout topRelativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
mainLinearLayout.addView(topRelativeLayout);

final TextView headerTextView = new TextView(this);
headerTextView.setText("Statistics");
topRelativeLayout.addView(headerTextView);

final ScrollView scrollView = new ScrollView(this);
mainLinearLayout.addView(scrollView);

final LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
scrollView.addView(linearLayout);

JSONArray users = response.getJSONArray("statistics");
for (int i = 0; i < users.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject result = users.getJSONObject(i);

    String id = result.getString("id");
    String userName = result.getString("username");

    int lastInsertIdInt = Integer.parseInt(id);

    statistics = new TextView[users.length()];
    statistics[i] = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    statistics[i].setText(id + userName);
    linearLayout.addView(statistics[i]);

    if(lastInsertIdInt == users.length()) {
        statistics[i].setTextColor(Color.RED);
        scrollView.scrollTo(0, statistics[i].getBottom()); // doesn't work
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: add some static value and check like scrollView.scrollTo(5, 12);

Comment: I tried to do this, but also nothing happens. Any other idea? Thnaks

Comment: if(lastInsertIdInt == users.length())  to if(i == users.length() -1)  and check

Comment: It just sets `TextColor` to an element before it, but no scroll.

Comment: scrollView.scrollTo(0, statistics[i].getBottom()); please remove .getBottom() then check.

Comment: If i remove `.getBottom()` i get this error: `Wrong 2nd argument type. Found 'android.widget.TextView' required 'int'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem in this way:

```
statistics[i].getParent().requestChildFocus(statistics[i], statistics[i]);
```